# String with \n in single string android

Tags: android

I have multiple value in single string, but I want to send in every string value on new line. I have written the following code, but it's not working.

```
 String text ="Address" + strpropertyAddress +"\n"+ "Price" + strPrice;
```

This is my service method where i pass the string.

```
sendPropertyApi(text, sendto);
```

I have checked every where, and it is exactly same. Basically the string data should be sent in on a new line, but it's sent in on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming(Because of Android tag) you are setting this text in `textView` or `editText`, for that I think you have to escape `\`. So use `\\n` instead. Try following:

```
String text ="Address" + strpropertyAddress +"\\n"+ "Price" + strPrice;
```

Or it is always better to use default line separator like following:

```
String text ="Address" + strpropertyAddress +System.getProperty("line.separator")+ "Price" + strPrice;
```